# Using TeamCity with GitHub for Windows

Tags: git, github, build-automation, teamcity-7.0

I am using TeamCity 7.1, running it on my Windows development machine. I have a team using GitHub for Windows. I am working on a demo for continuous integration. I want to teach the others how to setup TeamCity to work with a GitHub account. The less configuration they have to do the better.

TeamCity is asking for the path to the git executable and an ssh key. I've done this many times on my Ubuntu box, no problem, but never on a Windows box. It would be nice if I could reuse the GitHub for Windows command line and its private key store just for demonstration purposes. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The git.exe of "GithHub for Windows" is located at:

```
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_{hash}\bin\git.exe
```

It seems like the **hash** in the path is different on different systems.

By default Github for Windows clones github repos over HTTPS. Just for your demonstration purpose, in the **VCS root setting** of Teamcity build, you can use https url of your Github repo and choose "**Password**" as the "**Authentication Method**" in the "**Authentication settings**" section.

If you use "agent-side checkout", using "Password" as authentication method is supported only if you have **Teamcity 7.1.2+** and **git version 1.7.3+**. See [Git VCS settings Teamcity](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/Git+%28JetBrains%29) and Teamcity issue [TW-18711](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-18711).